# Search for column names and copy data

Tags: excel, vba

```
Workbook1 - Sheet 1:
Unique ID (Column D) | Line ID (Column Q) | Date1 (Column AL) | Date2 (Column AN) | Date3 (Column AO)| Date4 (Column AP)| Date5 (Column AQ)

Workbook 2 - Sheet 2: 
Unique ID (Column B) | Line ID (Column C) | Date1 (Column E) | Date2 (Column F) | Date3 (Column G)| Date4 (Column H)| Date5 (Column I)
```

I have 7 columns in my first workbook's sheet that I want to copy to the respective columns in my second workbook's sheet.

The column number of the columns I require might change. Therefore, I do not want to declare the variable by the column such as w="B" for example. Instead, I want to search for the columns with its name such as "LineID" and if the name matches to a column name then copy the data to the columns in another workbook's sheet.

These columns in sheet 1 are not in order as there are many columns in between. The order of the columns also changes as per the admin who enters the data. So I want to search for the columns with their names and get the data below it. Then copy it to another sheet.

I copied the data by specifying each column to copy but incase the column changes I'd have to go back to my code and change the column value. Instead it would be easier if the column is identified by its heading.

I am not good at VBA, any help to solve this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: No need for VBA. You can use the `MATCH` function to determine the column; and `INDEX` to return all the rows in that column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can copy and paste the following code into a new module. It can go in a new workbook, or either of the workbooks you are copying to/from.

As noted in the inline comments, you need to update the Set wsSrc and Set wsDest lines to match the your workbook and worksheet names.

For it to work without further modification, you need to have both workbooks open (the one you are copying from (Source) and the one you are pasting to (Destination)). Additionally your headers need to be in row 1.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub CopyData()

    ' DECLARE VARIABLES
    Dim i As Integer            ' Counter
    Dim j As Integer            ' Counter
    Dim colsSrc As Integer      ' Source worksheet columns
    Dim colsDest As Integer     ' Destination worksheet columns
    Dim rowsSrc As Long         ' Source worksheet rows excluding header
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet      ' Source worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet     ' Destination worksheet
    
    ' SET VARIABLES
    Set wsSrc = Workbooks("Source.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1")           ' Source worksheet (change Source.xlsx and Sheet1 to match your workbook name and worksheet name)
    Set wsDest = Workbooks("Destination.xlsx").Sheets("Sheet1")     ' Destination worksheet (change Destination.xlsx and Sheet1 to match your workbook name and worksheet name)
    colsSrc = wsSrc.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column    ' Source worksheet columns (assumes header is row 1)
    colsDest = wsDest.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column  ' Destination worksheet columns (assumes header is row 1)
    rowsSrc = wsSrc.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 1        ' Source worksheet rows excluding header (assumes header is row 1
    
    ' COPY DATA FROM SOURCE WORKSHEET TO DESTINATION WORKSHEET _
    - Compares each column header in your destination workbook to each column in your source workbook _
    - If a match is found, copies the column from the source workbook and pastes it into the destination workbook
    For i = 1 To colsDest
        For j = 1 To colsSrc
            If wsSrc.Cells(1, j) = wsDest.Cells(1, i) Then
                wsSrc.Cells(2, j).Resize(rowsSrc, 1).Copy wsDest.Cells(2, i)
                Exit For
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub
```